# PyDev: Debugger giving nameError whenever access class Members

Tags: pydev

I am working on debugging a project and now whenever I am in debug mode (Python 2.7.15) and trying to reference a class member (ex: visa_device.protocols) it gives NameError: global name 'dict_keys' is not defined.  It was working as expected previously and cannot recall any changes to the project that would have caused this issue. Only thing I can maybe think of was adding the SDKs to the project python path but can't imagine that would have caused this issue?

**Full Error Message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1211, in do_it
    msg = _pydev_completer.generate_completions_as_xml(frame, self.act_tok)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc_pydev_bundle_pydev_completer.py", line 167, in generate_completions_as_xml
    completions = pydevconsole.get_completions(act_tok, act_tok, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 462, in get_completions
    interpreterInterface.interpreter.update(globals, locals)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 350, in update
    for key in dict_keys(self.ipython.user_ns):
NameError: global name 'dict_keys' is not defined

Edit: Removed ipython 5.7.0 and debugger is now working as expected - odd behavior since it was installed last time when it was running.  Will continue to investigate.

Comment: This is a bug in 6.3.3. It's already fixed in master, just waiting for me to do a new release.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, really great work you're doing!  I do plan on being a paetreon soon

Comment: Thanks for the support ;)